# What determines the maximum number of trade routes a city can have?

Tags: freeciv

When a new city is founded, it is limited to two trade routes. Eventually, the game allows that city to have three trade routes. Further on in the game, the city is allowed to have four trade routes (the maximum possible in the game).

What determines the maximum number of trade routes a city can have at any given moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question; I've had to look this up several times in the past few weeks,
and found it in the [NEWS](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/master/NEWS) file:

> ### MAJOR CHANGES FROM 2.4.x to 2.5.0

[...]

> ```
>  * The maximum number of trade routes per city is now
>    ruleset-dependent. In the classic and (of as RC1) experimental
>    rulesets, the limit on trade routes now depends on what technology
>    you have. You start with 2 per city, and can add one more with each
>    of 'Magnetism' and 'The Corporation'.
> ```

The in-game *Help* should really explain this, but I don't think it supports ruleset-specific information yet.

To be sure, check the `effects.ruleset` of the ruleset you're playing with.  For instance, `data/classic/effects.ruleset` has:

```
[effect_trade_routes_base]
type    = "Max_Trade_Routes"
value   = 2

[effect_trade_routes_magnetism]
type    = "Max_Trade_Routes"
value   = 1
reqs    =
    { "type", "name", "range"
      "Tech", "Magnetism", "Player"
    }

[effect_trade_routes_corporation]
type    = "Max_Trade_Routes"
value   = 1
reqs    =
    { "type", "name", "range"
      "Tech", "The Corporation", "Player"
    }
```